# Does obstruction freedom imply starvation freedom too?

Tags: multithreading, nonblocking

A method is obstruction-free if a thread runs in isolation for long enough and then completes that method in finite steps. Whereas starvation freedom for a method ensures that all the threads calling that method will eventually complete in finite steps and there is system wide progress in all threads.

Now if all obstruction free methods are run in isolation for long enough, they will complete and this ensures progress across all threads. Also to note, both obstruction free and starvation freedom are dependent conditions i.e. ensure that the OS scheduler is fair.

So I feel that obstruction freedom implies starvation freedom. Only difference is that obstruction-free condition has been defined for non-blocking algorithms. On the other hand, starvation free condition is for blocking algorithms. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if all obstruction free methods are run in isolation for long enough, they will complete and this ensures progress across all threads.

That's a big "if".

> Also to note, both obstruction free and starvation freedom are dependent conditions i.e. ensure that the OS scheduler is fair.

I don't understand what you mean (perhaps that they *require* that the scheduler is fair; obstruction freedom does not ensure it. But I don't believe this is accurate. Obstruction freedom doesn't require the scheduler to be fair).

> So I feel that obstruction freedom implies starvation freedom

No, because there is no guarantee that the obstruction-free methods *will* get to run in isolation; this would require all the other processes to stop, and that requires them to either make progress and complete, or to be starved. If it was guaranteed they could make progress, you'd have at least Lock-freedom.

See the [Wikipedia entry on non-blocking algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) for a breakdown. Obstruction freedom is "the *weakest* natural non-blocking progress guarantee" (emphasis mine). This implies that starvation freedom (implied only by Wait freedom) is a *stronger* guarantee. Starvation freedom implies obstruction freedom, not the other way around.